# React-Redux: Logic inside mapStateToProps does not cause re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am wondering the "why" behind this behavior I am seeing in `react-redux`'s `mapStateToProps` pattern. I didn't put all my reducers, actions, etc in my question because I don't think those are the issues.

**video.component.tsx**

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  // valid activeVideoState are: 'prejoin' | 'active'
  prejoin: state.video.activeVideoState === 'prejoin', 
});

class _VideoComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this.checkJoinState();
  }

  componentWillUpdate () {
    this.checkJoinState();
  }

  async checkJoinState () {
    if (!this.props.prejoin) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }

  // rest of file class
}

// the `withRouter()` shouldn't affect anything
export const VideoComponent = withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(_VideoComponent));
```

Here is a snippet of my reducer (just to ensure that I am only using copies and not mutating my state):

**video.reducer.ts**

```js
const initialState = {
  activeVideoState: 'prejoin',
};

export const videoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VIDEO_STARTED: {
      return { ...state, activeVideoState: 'active' };
    }
    // other cases
  } 
  return state;
}
```

**video.actions.ts**

```js
export const sessionStarted = (sessionId: string) => ({
  type: VIDEO_STARTED,
  sessionId
});
```

**service.ts**

```js
import { store } from '@store/store';

// rxjs observable to listen to a WS for a video to start
this.onVideoStarted()
  .subscribe((session) => {
    // code 
    store.dispatch(sessionStarted(session.id));
  });
```

When the component initially renders, `state.video.activeVideoState === 'prejoin'` is *always* `true`. But over the life of the component, `state.video.activeVideoState` changes to `active`. The way this component is setup, the `VideoComponent` *never* re-renders even though I can clearly see the redux state has changed (using the react-redux browser extension).

*But*, if I change my function to look like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  // valid activeVideoState are: 'prejoin' | 'active'
  prejoin: state.video.activeVideoState === 'prejoin', 
  _iDontUseThis: state.video.activeVideoState
});
```

Then my component will update and re-render. I am just curious as to *why* this is happening. I understand the redux pattern pretty well, but I don't know the internals. I saw there are [options](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object) you can pass into `connect()`. Maybe the `areStatesEqual()` function looks at references rather than values?

Comment: Can you show the code where you dispatch VIDEO_STARTED?

Comment: I added them as **video.actions.ts** and **service.ts**

Comment: why SESSION_STARTED? in your reducer you used VIDEO_STARTED?

Comment: It's difficult to help with-out seeing more from your code. Can you please create a minimal example at Codesandbox? You can use the following as starting point https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-react-redux-example-hlod6

Comment: What is `@store/store`? But if it's the created store then the dispatch should work as you dispatched it. Just `SESSION_STARTED` is not matching your reducer action type `VIDEO_STARTED`.

Comment: `SESSION_START` was a typo in my question. I changed the constants in my question because there are alot of "session" things in my actual code. I updated my question with the change.

Comment: `@store/store` is a webpack/tsconfig alias for `src/store/` directory. Here is a repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-react-redux-example-en5cz

Answer (score 0):

This didn't appear to be an issue with `redux` at all. I just happened to notice that I was using the wrong component hook. When I switched them, my component started re-rendering. I couldn't get the faulty behavior to work in the repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-react-redux-example-en5cz

Changed:

```js
// deprecated
componentWillUpdate() { }
// to this
componentDidUpdate() { }
```

I don't know why that made the difference, but it did.

Comment: Using `store.dispatch()` [is anti-pattern](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#can-i-call-storedispatch), so employing `connect()` method together with `mapStateToProps()` would be preferrable option anyways.

Comment: Is it an anti-pattern to call `store.dispath()` from a service? That is how I am using it right now (calling it from `service.ts`). I have services that manage singletons and other 3rd party libs that can't and shouldn't be managed by redux.